# Cannot ssh into EC2 instance. Operation timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6c88.png)The security group allows SSH at port 22 [Inbound Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXF5X.png)

This is the first time I've had this problem. I logged in from a friend's AWS account to one of his instances and it connects. so the problem isn't at my end.

Here's the debug log:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "ec2-54-215-233-245.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-215-233-245.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [54.215.233.245] port 22.
```

I followed AWS's troubleshooting guide and even that didn't work. Any idea what's wrong?

[image: NACL]

Comment: Is your instance in a private subnet?

Comment: @Rafael apparently not: "Connecting to ec2-54-215-233-245.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"

Comment: But when you created it, did you make something different about the VPC? (did you change the default values of Network, or Subnet?)

Comment: @ishan the command used for ssh?

Comment: @hjpotter92 ssh -i "key.pem" ubuntu@DNS -vvv

Comment: @Rafael No, I didn't change anything.

Comment: To debug, you could select your instance then use "Launch more like this" to copy the settings. Change the AMI to a known-good configuration (eg Amazon Linux) and launch the instance. If you can connect to it, then that eliminates network and security group as the problem, so the issue would be with the boot disk itself.

Answer (score 3):

The standard things to check when you can't SSH into an instance:

- Confirm that the **Security Group** is permitting access on port 22 (SSH)
- Confirm that the instance is in a **Public Subnet** (which has a Route Table for the Subnet that sends traffic for `0.0.0.0/0` to the Internet Gateway)
- Confirm that the instance is running **Linux** or has an SSH service installed
- Confirm the **Public IP address** (if you're not using a static Elastic IP address, it can change when the instance is Stopped and Started)
- Confirm that the **Network Access Control Lists (NACLs)** in VPC permit all inbound and outbound traffic (this is the default setting)

Comment: Yes, I added an entry for port 22 in NACLs, the instance is in a public subnet & running Ubuntu. Posted a pic of the security group and NACL (edited).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to your key.pem's permission not securely set.  You might want to try set it to 0400 or 0600 (e.g. `sudo chmod 400 key.pem`).

Comment: If this were the case, `ssh` would display a message stating that fact.

Comment: @John Rotenstein, thanks for point that out. Contemporary ssh clients seem to address key permission issues well, with explicit warning like `Permissions 0444 for '/path/to/key.pem' are too open`.

Comment: The key's permission is 0400.

Comment: @ishan Vadwala, if your instance is EBS-backed and if all else fails, consider the recovery method described in this [AWS doc](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598) – essentially using a rescue instance which you can ssh to in the same availability zone to regain access to the unreachable instance.  Note that the first half of the doc goes over how to create an unreachable instance just as an exercise to illustrate how to fix it in the rescue section.